# how to access frontend files from backend

Tags: yii2, alias, yii2-advanced-app

I want to print an image in a backend view. the image exists in frontend, so I used the alias to print it like:

```
<img src="<?= Yii::getAlias('@frontendWeb') . "/uploads/clients/{$model->img}"; ?>"/>
```

where the `@frontendWeb` alias is defined in `common\config\bootstrap` as:

```
Yii::setAlias('@frontendWeb', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend/web');
```

the image URL is true, and I can see it if I open its URL directly from the browser, but unfortunately it didn't shown in the view file.

Comment: You set alias to path of the file on disk, not url. Try to use `Yii::setAlias('@frontendWeb', '/frontend/web');`

Comment: @MarcinGordel didn't work

Comment: @see pceuropa.net/blog/which-yii2-choose-basic-advanced/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use direct links, as the images in front-end are accessible publicly anyways

```
<img src="<?= Url::base(true) ?>"/uploads/clients/"<?= {$model->img} ?>"/>
```

Comment: if we use this code in backend, backend base url will be generated (not frontend).

Comment: You can always define frontend and backend UrlManagers and then reference the specific one where needed. :)

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlmanager

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<img src="<?= Yii::getAlias('@frontendWeb') . "/uploads/clients/" . $model->img . ".jpg" ?>" class="photos"/>
```

Comment: the image extension is already exist in the attribute, no need to put it statically

Comment: you can remove that :)

Comment: so now what is the difference between my trail and your answer? the same :)